# is there any way to skip cucumber scenarios while running unit steps?

Tags: maven, cucumber

`mvn install` is running cucumber steps also. in our local development, we need to run only unit tests and not the cucumber scenarios. Tried with `-Dtest=!com.mycompany.*` no luck.

And at the same time, we need to skip our Unit Tests while executing a cucumber scenario, is that possible?

Comment: U can configure surefire plugin to exclude or include test classes.

Comment: I tried with surefire configuration .. but they are like static setting. we are looking for command line options so that in local dev we can skip cucumber scenarios and in Jenkins Job, we can skip unit tests and run only required scenario.

Comment: Easier would be, by using profile. Refer to answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be achieved by using build profiles. You should run your unit tests by using the surefire plugin and the cucumber scenarios with the failsafe plugin. Naming conventions for automatic running of tests for [surefire](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html) and [failsafe](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html).

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>jenkins</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>**/*Test.java</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

Run this with `mvn clean install -Pjenkins`. This will only run the integration tests ie scenarios.

To run the unit tests just use `mvn clean install`. Surefire is invoked ie unit test, by default but not failsafe.